# How to grant permissions to SqlServer 2005 system stored procs (e.g. sp_start_job)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I want to be able to invoke an SSIS package at will from a web application.  I've found that I can do this successfully with sp_start_job when running on my local machine.  However, when I publish to our test site, I get:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_start_job', database 'msdb', schema dbo'
```

So I tried this

```
USE msdb

CREATE USER [TheUser] FOR LOGIN [TheLogin]
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_start_job TO [TheUser]
GO
```

However, after running this, I am still getting the permission denied error.  Is there something special you have to do to grant permissions to system stored procs?

Edit: don't know if it makes a difference or not, but the Webserver is in a DMZ, so I am using sql server authentication to communicate between webserver and db server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx):

> By default, members of the sysadmin
>   fixed server role can execute this
>   stored procedure. Other users must be
>   granted one of the following SQL
>   Server Agent fixed database roles in
>   the msdb database:
>
> ```
> * SQLAgentUserRole
> * SQLAgentReaderRole
> * SQLAgentOperatorRole
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The first two roles didn't work for me, but SQLAgentOperatorRole does.  The only thing is that it has slightly more permissions than I would like.  Is there any way to create my own role that *just* has the permission to execute the job?

Comment: For others who may have missed it, these are roles in the **msdb** database.